# Optimize Nested MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-5.7, conditional-aggregation

My Application is database-driven. I have written a query that is taking more than 15-20 minutes to execute. I have proper indexes, but still, it is taking too much time to execute. Below is my query, if anyone can help me optimize it, I will be very thankful.

```
        select p.id as product_id, p.product_name as product_name, p.product_category as product_category, p.brand as brand, p.sku_id as sku_id, p.product_priority as product_priority, p.quantity as quantity, p.pack as pack, p.unit as unit, p.size as size,
            
            (select group_concat(product_sku) from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no') as product_sku_amazon,
            (select group_concat(product_sku) from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no') as product_sku_flipkart,
            (select group_concat(product_sku) from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no') as product_sku_snapdeal,
            (select group_concat(product_sku) from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no') as product_sku_1mg,
            (select group_concat(product_sku) from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no') as product_sku_paytm,
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_amazon_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_amazon_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_amazon_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_amazon_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_amazon_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value/unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as asp_amazon_date_range,
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_amazon_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_amazon_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_amazon_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_amazon_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Amazon' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_amazon_mtd,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_quantity_amazon_daily_date_range,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_amazon_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_value_amazon_daily_date_range,
            (select target_selling_price_amazon_date_range) as target_selling_price_amazon_daily_date_range,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_quantity_amazon_daily_mtd,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_amazon_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_value_amazon_daily_mtd,
            (select target_selling_price_amazon_mtd) as target_selling_price_amazon_daily_mtd,
            
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_quantity_amazon_mte,
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_value_amazon_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_value_amazon_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_quantity_amazon_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_quantity_amazon_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_value_amazon_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_value_amazon_mte,
            
            
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_flipkart_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_flipkart_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_flipkart_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_flipkart_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_flipkart_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value/unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as asp_flipkart_date_range,
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_flipkart_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_flipkart_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_flipkart_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_flipkart_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_flipkart_mtd,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_quantity_flipkart_daily_date_range,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_flipkart_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_value_flipkart_daily_date_range,
            (select target_selling_price_flipkart_date_range) as target_selling_price_flipkart_daily_date_range,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_quantity_flipkart_daily_mtd,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_flipkart_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_value_flipkart_daily_mtd,
            (select target_selling_price_flipkart_mtd) as target_selling_price_flipkart_daily_mtd,
            
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_quantity_flipkart_mte,
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_value_flipkart_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_value_flipkart_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_quantity_flipkart_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_quantity_flipkart_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_value_flipkart_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_value_flipkart_mte,
            
            
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_snapdeal_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_snapdeal_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_snapdeal_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_snapdeal_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value/unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as asp_snapdeal_date_range,
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_snapdeal_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_snapdeal_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_snapdeal_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_snapdeal_mtd,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_daily_date_range,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_snapdeal_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_value_snapdeal_daily_date_range,
            (select target_selling_price_snapdeal_date_range) as target_selling_price_snapdeal_daily_date_range,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_daily_mtd,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_snapdeal_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_value_snapdeal_daily_mtd,
            (select target_selling_price_snapdeal_mtd) as target_selling_price_snapdeal_daily_mtd,
            
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_mte,
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_value_snapdeal_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_value_snapdeal_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_quantity_snapdeal_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_quantity_snapdeal_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_value_snapdeal_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_value_snapdeal_mte,
            
            
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_1mg_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_1mg_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_1mg_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_1mg_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_1mg_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value/unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as asp_1mg_date_range,
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_1mg_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_1mg_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_1mg_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_1mg_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='1MG' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_1mg_mtd,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_1mg_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_quantity_1mg_daily_date_range,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_1mg_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_value_1mg_daily_date_range,
            (select target_selling_price_1mg_date_range) as target_selling_price_1mg_daily_date_range,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_1mg_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_quantity_1mg_daily_mtd,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_1mg_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_value_1mg_daily_mtd,
            (select target_selling_price_1mg_mtd) as target_selling_price_1mg_daily_mtd,
            
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_quantity_1mg_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_quantity_1mg_mte,
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_value_1mg_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_value_1mg_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_quantity_1mg_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_quantity_1mg_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_value_1mg_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_value_1mg_mte,
            
            
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_paytm_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_paytm_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_paytm_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_paytm_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_paytm_date_range,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value/unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-18' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as asp_paytm_date_range,
            
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_quantity_paytm_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(target_sale_quantity*target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as target_sale_value_paytm_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(avg(target_selling_price)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as target_selling_price_paytm_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(unit_sold)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_quantity_paytm_mtd,
            ifnull((select round(sum(sale_value)) from sale_data where (date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-18') and product_id in (select id from product_master where product_category=p.product_category and portal='Paytm' and competitor='no')),0) as sale_value_paytm_mtd,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_paytm_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_quantity_paytm_daily_date_range,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_paytm_date_range)/1)),0) as target_sale_value_paytm_daily_date_range,
            (select target_selling_price_paytm_date_range) as target_selling_price_paytm_daily_date_range,
            
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_quantity_paytm_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_quantity_paytm_daily_mtd,
            ifnull((round((select target_sale_value_paytm_mtd)/18)),0) as target_sale_value_paytm_daily_mtd,
            (select target_selling_price_paytm_mtd) as target_selling_price_paytm_daily_mtd,
            
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_quantity_paytm_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_quantity_paytm_mte,
            ifnull(round((select target_sale_value_paytm_daily_mtd)*30),0) as target_sale_value_paytm_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_quantity_paytm_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_quantity_paytm_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select sale_value_paytm_mtd)/18)*30),0) as sale_value_paytm_mte,
            
            
            
            ((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_1mg_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_paytm_date_range)) as target_sale_quantity_total_date_range,
            ((select target_sale_value_amazon_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_flipkart_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_snapdeal_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_1mg_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_paytm_date_range)) as target_sale_value_total_date_range,
            ifnull(round(((select target_selling_price_amazon_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_flipkart_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_snapdeal_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_1mg_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_paytm_date_range))/5),0) as target_selling_price_total_date_range,
            ((select sale_quantity_amazon_date_range)+(select sale_quantity_flipkart_date_range)+(select sale_quantity_snapdeal_date_range)+(select sale_quantity_1mg_date_range)+(select sale_quantity_paytm_date_range)) as sale_quantity_total_date_range,
            ((select sale_value_amazon_date_range)+(select sale_value_flipkart_date_range)+(select sale_value_snapdeal_date_range)+(select sale_value_1mg_date_range)+(select sale_value_paytm_date_range)) as sale_value_total_date_range,
            ifnull(round(((select asp_amazon_date_range)+(select asp_flipkart_date_range)+(select asp_snapdeal_date_range)+(select asp_1mg_date_range)+(select asp_paytm_date_range))/5),0) as asp_total_date_range,
            
            ((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_1mg_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_paytm_mtd)) as target_sale_quantity_total_mtd,
            ((select target_sale_value_amazon_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_flipkart_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_snapdeal_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_1mg_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_paytm_mtd)) as target_sale_value_total_mtd,
            ifnull(round(((select target_selling_price_amazon_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_flipkart_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_snapdeal_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_1mg_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_paytm_mtd))/5),0) as target_selling_price_total_mtd,
            ((select sale_quantity_amazon_mtd)+(select sale_quantity_flipkart_mtd)+(select sale_quantity_snapdeal_mtd)+(select sale_quantity_1mg_mtd)+(select sale_quantity_paytm_mtd)) as sale_quantity_total_mtd,
            ((select sale_value_amazon_mtd)+(select sale_value_flipkart_mtd)+(select sale_value_snapdeal_mtd)+(select sale_value_1mg_mtd)+(select sale_value_paytm_mtd)) as sale_value_total_mtd,
            
            ((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_1mg_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_quantity_paytm_daily_date_range)) as target_sale_quantity_total_daily_date_range,
            ((select target_sale_value_amazon_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_flipkart_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_snapdeal_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_1mg_daily_date_range)+(select target_sale_value_paytm_daily_date_range)) as target_sale_value_total_daily_date_range,
            ifnull(round(((select target_selling_price_amazon_daily_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_flipkart_daily_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_snapdeal_daily_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_1mg_daily_date_range)+(select target_selling_price_paytm_daily_date_range))/5),0) as target_selling_price_total_daily_date_range,
            
            ((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_1mg_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_quantity_paytm_daily_mtd)) as target_sale_quantity_total_daily_mtd,
            ((select target_sale_value_amazon_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_flipkart_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_snapdeal_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_1mg_daily_mtd)+(select target_sale_value_paytm_daily_mtd)) as target_sale_value_total_daily_mtd,
            ifnull(round(((select target_selling_price_amazon_daily_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_flipkart_daily_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_snapdeal_daily_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_1mg_daily_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_paytm_daily_mtd))/5),0) as target_selling_price_total_daily_mtd,
            
            ((select target_sale_quantity_amazon_mte)+(select target_sale_quantity_flipkart_mte)+(select target_sale_quantity_snapdeal_mte)+(select target_sale_quantity_1mg_mte)+(select target_sale_quantity_paytm_mte)) as sale_target_quantity_total_mte,
            ((select target_sale_value_amazon_mte)+(select target_sale_value_flipkart_mte)+(select target_sale_value_snapdeal_mte)+(select target_sale_value_1mg_mte)+(select target_sale_value_paytm_mte)) as target_sale_value_total_mte,
            ifnull(round(((select target_selling_price_amazon_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_flipkart_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_snapdeal_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_1mg_mtd)+(select target_selling_price_paytm_mtd))/5),0) as target_selling_price_total_mte,
            ((select sale_quantity_amazon_mte)+(select sale_quantity_flipkart_mte)+(select sale_quantity_snapdeal_mte)+(select sale_quantity_1mg_mte)+(select sale_quantity_paytm_mte)) as sale_quantity_total_mte,
            ((select sale_value_amazon_mte)+(select sale_value_flipkart_mte)+(select sale_value_snapdeal_mte)+(select sale_value_1mg_mte)+(select sale_value_paytm_mte)) as sale_value_total_mte
            
            
            
            from product_master p
            where p.competitor='no' and p.parent_product_category in ('Mosquito Net')
            group by p.product_category
            order by sale_quantity_total_date_range desc
```

The above is a huge query and I have only this option to achieve desired result.I also have MySQL caching turned on, but it doesn't help.

Comment: that query has way, way, *way* too many instances of the word `select`

Comment: Hi @DanielFarrell Because i need the data in form where I am unable to use join. This is why I had to use sub query.

Comment: A [tag:query-optimization] question should include the output of [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) for each table in the query (as text please, not screenshots), and output of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) for the query.

Comment: But if you say you have already created the indexes needed, and you say you can't change the query syntax, and you don't think caching the query result will help, I don't know what other suggestions you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is too large for a volunteer to take on, to put it mildly. But I will point this out: It has dozens of dependent subqueries. Those are a notorious performance antipattern.

I know the first six dependent subqueries are completely unnecessary if you use conditional aggregation. Here's how I would rewrite this: it will probably be several times faster than what you have.

```
    select p.id as product_id, p.product_name as product_name,
           p.product_category as product_category, p.brand as brand,
           p.sku_id as sku_id, p.product_priority as product_priority,
           p.quantity as quantity, p.pack as pack,
           p.unit as unit, p.size as size,
           group_concat (
             if(portal='Amazon' and competitor='no', product_sku, null)) product_sku_amazon,
           group_concat (
             if(portal='Flipkart' and competitor='no', product_sku, null)) product_sku_flipkart,
           group_concat (
             if(portal='Snapdeal' and competitor='no', product_sku, null)) product_sku_snapdeal,
           group_concat (
             if(portal='IMG' and competitor='no', product_sku, null)) product_sku_img,
           group_concat (
              if(portal='paytm' and competitor='no', product_sku, null)) product_sku_paytm
      from product_master p
     where p.competitor='no' 
       and p.parent_product_category in ('Mosquito Net')
     group by p.product_category
```

This works because `GROUP_CONCAT()` ignores NULL values.

I suspect you can rewrite much of your query this way.